# how to replicate this C# initialization code in F#

Tags: f#

I have this in C#:

```
_RestClient.ConfigureWebRequest(r =>
{
    r.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    r.KeepAlive                      = true;
});
```

what is the syntax to replicate this in F#?

Comment: Without knowing what the APIs are it's very difficult to give an answer that will work. What is `_RestClient`, what is `ConfigureWebRequest`, etc.?

Comment: it can be anything really: a.b (x -> {x.c = true}); the issue is that it is not clear to me how to 'x' part comes to life in F#

Comment: Try something like `(fun r ->` and `r.KeepAlive <- true`.

Comment: Lambdas are `fun x ->` in F# and mutating a value is done with `x <- v`; but without knowing more about the API there's no way to verify an answer.

Comment: this works; that's the part I didn't know: how to express the lambda in F#. I have to apologize for the terse nature of the question, I'm fighting a hotel wifi in the mountains in Eastern Europe :)

Comment: This question is perfectly answerable as-is, and did not need to be closed. `_RestClient.ConfigureWebRequest(fun r -> r.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue <- false; r.KeepAlive <- true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda-expressions in F# are denoted `fun x -> ...` - equivalent to C# `x => ...`

Mutation (aka "assignment") is denoted `x <- y` - equivalent to C# `x = y`

So, to put that all together, you'd get this:

```
_RestClient.ConfigureWebRequest(fun r ->
    r.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue <- false
    r.KeepAlive <- true
)
```